# How to check if iframe(loaded from CDN script) content has loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, cdn

I'm adding an external CDN script in my react application, application has an `id="iframe-content"` and the script embeds an iframe in that id. Now I need to perform some functionality or update a state when this iframe's content has fully loaded. At the moment I'm using

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
        callReady()
    });

 function callReady() {
    // Get a handle to the iframe element
    var iframe = document.getElementById('i_frame');
    var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

    // Check if loading is complete
    if (iframeDoc.readyState == 'complete') {
        iframe.contentWindow.onload = function () {
            alert("I am loaded");
        };

        afterLoading();
        return;
    }
    window.setTimeout(callReady, 100);
}

function afterLoading() {
    alert("I am here");
}
```

I have also tried

```
iframe.onload = function(event) {
        console.log('loaded')
    };
```

Nothing actually works, actual iframe content loads after every load function. I need to be able to know when the actual iframe content has loaded. Can you please help me out here?

Comment: does the iframe load another iframe? This is fairly common in 3rd party libraries

Comment: No, that is the only iframe that gets loaded in my application's id.